# Selectivly replace certain HTML tags via PHP while keeping some

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I've got a form that contains html code that occasionally get's a little bit messy because of the MCE editor's auto-formatting that I cannot disable.

I'm already doing a few simple replaces with PHP but a few others I am not so sure about.

Remove **ALL** `<span>` tags for example `<span style="font-family: inherit; font-weight: inherit; line-height: 1.3;">` including their `</span>` counterparts but **NOT** the content inside of those tags.

For example: `<span style="font-family: inherit; font-weight: inherit; line-height: 1.3;">StackOverflow</span>` **would turn into just** `StackOverflow`

The only ones that should **NOT** be removed are ones that look like:

`<span class="MainLink" style="font-weight: bold"><a href="https://website.com/" style="color: #2f82de; text-decoration: none">link name</a></span>`

So basically any that are encapsulating a `<a href...` link.

Any ideas how this can be done, I assume I'd need to use regex to do it but there might be an easier/better way.

Comment: To clarify, you don't also want to remove the contents of the `<span></span>`? Just the wrapping?

Comment: 4castle yes, sorry. I'll edit and make that clear. I had been trying to make myself some regex but I am terrible at them. `^\<span.+\>$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform this operation you need a Parser, not a regular expression (see also [The Famous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3294262) about this)

Start from this example with `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->formatOutput = True;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

while( $node = $xpath->query( '//span[not(contains(@class,"MainLink"))]' )->item(0) )
{
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    while( $node->childNodes->length ) 
    {
        $fragment->appendChild( $node->childNodes->item(0) );
    }
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild( $fragment, $node );
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

With this line:

```
while( $node = $xpath->query( '//span[not(contains(@class,"leave"))]' )->item(0) )
```

you search for every `<span>` node that not contains “leave” in `class` attribute: the loop is executed while this pattern if found (`->item(0)`).

Then you create a new `DOMDocumentFragment`, a special temporary node in which you add all the children:

```
    while( $node->childNodes->length ) 
    {
        $fragment->appendChild( $node->childNodes->item(0) );
    }
```

After moving all node children to new fragment, you replace empty `<span>` node with the fragment.

---

**Other useful XPath that can help you:**

- `//span[not(a)]` : select all `<span>` node not followed by a `<a>` child;
- `//span[not(contains(@class,"leave")) and not(contains(@class,"yes"))]` : select all `<span>` node without “leave” or “yes” in `class` attribute.

Comment: Despite responding with a regex myself (for better or worse, I read the question as asking for that and obliged), to do true HTML editing of any kind, @fusion3k's answer here is conceptually the correct one. PHP's DOM parsing is clunky and debugging is an awful pain when object properties are hidden away, but traversing the DOM is the only real reliable way to make sure unforeseen cases for regex matching don't make your life a nightmare, and PHP's DOM parsing will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$output = preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>(?!<a[ >])|(?<!\/a>)<\/span>/', '', $input);
```

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/aZ1nO9/8)

This regex has ***two parts*** to it:

1. It removes any `<span>` that doesn't have `<a` right after it.
2. It removes any `</span>` that doesn't have `/a>` right before it.

**Note**: This solution is a quick fix to the question and assumes valid HTML. There is likely some scenario where this will not work properly, but the OP will probably not have any of those scenarios (a self-closing `a` tag inside a `span` for example). See the Regex101 for a demonstration of the scenarios that *are* accounted for.

Comment: Let me know if this works, I may not know enough about your test cases.

Comment: How would I then use that with, I assume `preg_replace()`?

Comment: I have updated my answer once again and further explained the regex to make it shine. Let me know of any bugs that I can fix if you find something wrong.

Comment: Works beautifully, I'll be using either this one or the other one from xjstratedgebx because of how simple my task is, I know the parser route is better logically and for bigger projects.

Comment: Great! Yeah, I agree. And for the sake of advocating my answer, this regex is nearly twice as fast as his and doesn't break with nested `span` tags.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to switch up capturing groups**

I always find doing things like this to be really tricky, since there tends to be so many unforeseen cases that may need to be dealt with or they come back to bite me.

That being said, the challenge of this kind of regex is usually a lot of fun.

I'd probably try something like this:

`(?:<span[^>]*?>)(?!<a)(.*?)(?:<\/span>)`

In action here: https://regex101.com/r/qY8pL5/3

What it does is first try to match the opening of a span tag, and find where the opening tag most likely ends. This is put into a non-capturing group so it can be discarded. Next it makes sure that the next two characters do not being an anchor tag, as a span wrapping an anchor should not be stripped. The next part is a capturing group that grabs every character as lazily as possible until it reaches a closing span tag. The closing span tag is also collected in a non-capturing group so it can be discarded.

This will match standalone span tags and span tags wrapped in anchors. It will not match span tags that wrap anchors.

In php you would implement it like this:

```
$final_string = preg_replace('/(?:<span[^>]*?>)(?!<a)(.*?)(?:<\/span>)/', '${1}', $string);
```

The first parameter is our regex, the second is what we want to use as replacement for what our regex matches - in this case the first (and in this case only) capturing group is preserved - and lastly we pass the string we wish to match against.

---

Please note @fusion3k's is the best answer so far written than provides a comprehensive methodology for doing any kind of real HTML parsing.

Comment: While this regex should work for the specific case presented in the question, the fullest answer at the moment of writing this is @fusion3k's answer about opting for DOM traversal over regex for any and all HTML parsing. I'd recommend that approach over this one.

Comment: The question clarifies that it doesn't want the html inside the `span` tags removed, just the `span` tags. This removes the html inside.

Comment: Good point, I got the capturing groups backwards. As originally written, it would remove all the content between the opening and close span tags, whether HTML or plain text. Will update - though again, for the OP, @fusion3k's answer is the correct one conceptually.

Comment: That's much better. But I should point out that this regex still has problems if there is a `span` inside a `span`. Also, I agree that @fusion3k has the safest answer, but for a quick fix, regex can work fine here. The algorithm isn't overly complex.

Comment: Yeah, my interpretation of the question was just the container span, and leaving its contents alone, even if that had another span it. My guess is a second span inside the container would match the first closing span and break some things. Goes back to my opening thought that externalities can make regex parsing tricky every time you come across something you didn't plan for for sure.